# ClickOnce and Dll : how this works?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll, clickonce

I want to deploy a ClickOnce VS app. My problem is that I'm using localdb with SMO. For localdb, it's easy, I just add it as prerequiste in the property->publish page. But, SMO is more complex. My first move was to put the dll that I need (ConnectionInfo.dll, Management.Sdk.Sfc.dll, Smo.dll and SqlEnum.dll) in a folder inside my project and, in the Application Files section, mark them as "include", but it doesn't go as good as planned. The app include the dll and works well when I install it, but that end there. I need Microsoft.SqlServer.BatchParserClient.dll to works with the other dll.

After some research, I realize that I need to install SMO.msi, so it would install BatchParserClient in the GAC. But I would rather want not to install SMO. So, is there a way that I set the BatchParserClient.dll as a dependency to the project and include it in the same as the other dll, even if I'm not using it directly in my code. Or is it possible, when installing my app with ClickOnce, to install BatchClientParser in the GAC (I read somewhere that no, but I still ask) ?

Thank you,
David Lefaivre-B.

Comment: Add your dlls to project from file system and set CopyLocal true.So you will not need them into GAC. After that you can configure your clickonce

Comment: Thank you, but I'm not sure to understand. All the 4 "needed" dlls and the "extra" dll are in my project and have all a references. By setting it to CopyLocal true, you mean the reference, right ? This is what I do, and the batchParserClient.dll is still not in the Application Files section, so I can't do the same as the other dlls and set it to "include". I try to create a ClickOnce application anyway, without any more config, and the problem is the same. Anything I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: Do you have reference on  batchParserClient.dll in your application now?

Comment: Yeah, sorry for the lack of answer. I wasn't looking for the good file. Now I feel a little bit stupid